# Count amount of mappings

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
let xs = [ "1"; "1"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1" ]
let ys = [ "0"; "0"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1" ]

let replace x y =
    match x = y with
    | false -> "-"
    | true -> x

xs |> Seq.zip ys |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> replace x y) |> Seq.toList
```

which gives following correct result:

`val it: string list = ["-"; "-"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1"]`

My problem is, that I need to know how often the substitiution to "-" had happend. In case of more than one I have to discard the new list.

I tried to implment my own "map" and count the calls:

```
let myMap f xs =
    let rec innerMap f xs : ('T list * int) =
        match xs with
        | [], c -> [], c
        | h :: tail, c ->
            match innerMap f (tail, c + 1) with
            |lst, c -> [(f h)] @ lst, c

    innerMap f (xs, 0)
```

But now my `replace` isn't working anymore (expects list, gets string?) and `myMap` would only work with `list` and not with `seq`.

Another thing is, that the lists could become very long. If I know that there are already more than one substitution, I could stop before traversing the complete list.

How could I count how often the replacement took place?

**Edit**: got "myMap" compiling and now I get the amount of all maps:

`(["-"; "-"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1"], 6)`

Still need to know how oftern `replace` was "successful".

**Edit**:
Changed my `replace` function to:

```
let replace x y =
    match x = y with
    | false -> "-", 1
    | true -> x, 0
```

and `myMap` to:

```
let myMap f xs =
    let rec innerMap f xs : ('T list * int) =
        match xs with
        | [], c -> [], c
        | h :: tail, c ->
            match innerMap f (tail, c) with
            |lst, c -> match (f h) with
                       |x,y -> [x] @ lst, y + c

    innerMap f (xs, 0)
```

which gives me:

```
val it: string list * int = (["-"; "-"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1"], 2)
```

Is there a better way to do that instead of having a custom map and changing `replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something with every element of the input collection and passing a state variable through these computations is a `fold` operation, not a `map`. In F#, there's a variant provided (`fold2`) that is taking the elements from two input collections, obviating the `zip`.

The forward `fold` would give you the result in the wrong order, so maybe `foldBack2` might be a better choice (as well as an opportunity to break out the `op_PipeRight3`):

```
(xs, ys, ([], 0))
|||> List.foldBack2 (fun x y (xs, c) ->
    if x = y then x::xs, c
    else "-"::xs, c + 1 )
// val it : string list * int = (["-"; "-"; "-"; "1"; "1"; "1"], 2)
```

Comment: that's insane! I have to dive into that! Thx!